# cusel.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in #<error>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to use cusel.js (styled selects) library on my selects, but It's does not work - selects are changing, but when I try to scroll over select options using jscrollpane, which is used for scrolling by Cusel, in JavaScript console I see unknown to me error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' 
in #<error> (file jquery.js, line 9217).
```

My versions of libraries:

```
Jquery v1.7.2
cusel version 2.5
jquery.jscrollpane.js - tried all versions of this library, still does not work.
jquery.mousewheel.js - tried all possible versions, still does not work.
```

There is my code of calling `cuSel`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var params = {
        changedEl: ".lineForm select",
        visRows:7,                
    }
    cuSel(params);
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try with a more recent version of jQuery?  They're on 1.9.1 now.

Comment: I tried with 1.9.1, now Chrome returns error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
And Firebug in Firefox returns
TypeError: $.browser is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You may substitute code of cusel plugin from [here](https://gist.github.com/biakaveron/4023162) 
here bug was fixed and plugin was adapted to jquery v1.7+